# Rename column headers when I resize the page

Tags: sapui5

### I want to rename the column headers of my table when I change the size of the page.

I have tried detecting the width of the screen and then added the if conditions according to which I want to change the Column header. But the problem is as I have set the minimum screen width as desktop and my code is only responding if my width of the page go ***lower than 1024px else it is not responsive***.

```
var oTable = that.getView().byId("monTable");
oTable.addEventDelegate({
            "onAfterRendering": function () {


                    if (that.getView().$().width() < 1764) {

                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[6].getHeader().setText("Fehler");
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[7].getHeader().setText("Warnung");

                    }

                    if (that.getView().$().width() < 1520) {
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[6].getHeader().setText("Fehler");
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[7].getHeader().setText("Warnung");
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[9].getHeader().setText("MG");

                    }

                    if (that.getView().$().width() < 1404) {
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[6].getHeader().setText("Fehler");
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[7].getHeader().setText("WN");

                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[13].getHeader().setText("Status");
                    }

                    if (that.getView().$().width() < 1356) {
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[6].getHeader().setText("Fehler");
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[7].getHeader().setText("WN");

                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[13].getHeader().setText("Status");
                    }

                    if (that.getView().$().width() < 1278) {

                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[12].getHeader().setText("FG");
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[13].getHeader().setText("Status");
                    }

                    if (that.getView().$().width() < 1206) {
                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[6].getHeader().setText("FH");

                        that.getView().byId("monTable").getColumns()[13].getHeader().setText("ST");
                    }
                }
```

The expected result should change the header according to the width I have set in my if conditions but it is not responding. But if you reload the page after changing the screen with then every time it is responding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ResizeHandler (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.ResizeHandler/methods/sap.ui.core.ResizeHandler.register) to call the function everytime the window changes.

```
ResizeHandler.register(this.getView().byId("xyz"), this._onResize.bind(this));
```

The _onResize method then contains the logic you have posted regarding the change of the texts.

The control you attach it to could be your `sap.m.Page` or whatever your container is.

For this to work you would also need to require `sap/ui/core/ResizeHandler` as ResizeHandler.